# Tokenizing a string inside a switch statement - C

Tags: c, switch-statement, strtok

I've been having a lot of trouble using strtok in a switch statement . Here's the code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char phrase[256];
  printf("type a phrase to examine\n\n");
  fgets(phrase, 256, stdin);

  printf("phrase: %s\n", phrase);

  int opt;

  while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "l")) != -1) {
     switch (opt) {
     case 'l':
         //prints all words as a list
         char *token = strtok(phrase, " ");

         while (token != NULL) {
             printf("%s\n", token);
             token = strtok(NULL, " ");
             break;
         }
     }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

When it prints, it only shows me the first word but nothing else after the spaces

i've also tried using strtok when it's not in the switch statement but it works fine. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You break out of the `while` loop on the first iteration. `break` shouldn't be inside the loop if you want to see all tokens.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `switch`, it would happen the same if you used `if`

Comment: That's it!! That fixed the entire problem, thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `break;` statement should be out of the `while` loop.  You should have realized yourself had you indented properly the source (I edited your question, to make it more apparent, although).

After the first pass through the loop, you get the `break;` and you get out of the loop, instead of getting out of the `switch` statement.

```
     case 'l':
         //prints all words as a list
         char *token = strtok(phrase, " ");

         while (token != NULL) {
             printf("%s\n", token);
             token = strtok(NULL, " ");
         }
         break;  /* now the break gets out of the switch */
```

will do a better job.

There's a more readable way, IMHO, that will allow you to use a `for` loop:

```
         //prints all words as a list
         for (char *token = strtok(phrase, " ");
              token != NULL;
              token = strtok(NULL, " "))
         {
             printf("%s\n", token);
         }
```